# How debug at the same time NodeJs server and React client in a clean way accessing client through server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, devops

How can I debug node and react in a clean way? I thought to start the node server in a vscode window, and react server in another window, so 2 servers running but isn't it ugly?

Comment: You can use the Concurrently npm module to run both the servers at the same time.